# Reverse CRC16 calculation

Tags: reverse-engineering, crc16

I'm trying to understand how is calculated the CRC at the end of a radio packet.

Here are a few examples:

- <strike>11 00 01 0D 30 10 05 1F 11 ED 7E 01 00 01 B9 33</strike>
- 11 00 01 0D 30 10 05 1F 11 ED 7E 01 00 00 B9 32
- 11 00 01 1D 30 10 05 1F 11 ED 7E 01 00 00 EA CC
- 11 00 01 2D 30 10 05 1F 11 ED 7E 01 00 00 1E CE

The 4th byte is a sequence number. All other bytes are constant. The last 2 bytes definitely look like a CRC16, as these are the only ones changing when the sequence byte increases. The last 2 bytes are not related to the time, as I can reproduce that exact same sequence anytime.

Here are a few more examples, from the same device but with a different command:

- 16 00 01 60 20 10 05 1F 11 ED 7E 01 02 00 04 00 02 00 65 32 CC
- 16 00 01 CB 20 10 31 53 11 ED 7E 01 42 00 04 00 02 00 65 B4 B9

This time again, the last 2 bytes look like a CRC16.

I've tried many CRC calculations, using online calculators like [crccalc.com](https://crccalc.com/).
I've also used the [RevEng](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/) tool, but got no results.

I can't figure out the method of calculation, so I must be missing something.
Any help to determine the calculation would be welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: "All other bytes are constant." Not quite. The third-to-the-last byte changes.

Comment: You're right. I've updated the first example. The previous example was representing a different state of the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [CRC-16/XMODEM](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat.crc-16-xmodem), computed on your examples with the first three bytes and the last two bytes before the CRC removed, and then, oddly, that CRC exclusive-or'ed with the two bytes that precede it (those that were excluded from the CRC calculation). The resulting 16-bit value is appended in big-endian order.

Comment: You're 100% right. Using CRC16/XMODEM, then XOR on those bytes is always correct for each packet I've tested. I'm impressed you came up with the solution so quickly for such an odd "encryption". Many thanks!